# Have 2 different forms on website, but clicking on either of them, redirects to the same php

Tags: php, html, forms, redirect

We were doing a project which involved a website and a database. We decided to host it using 000webhost.

So, we have 2 different forms, and both should redirect to different PHPs, but both end up redirecting to the same php.

I have attached the code of the forms here:

```
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
       <form action="csignup.php">
              <div class="container">
                 <label><b>NAME<b></label><br>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Fullname" name="fname" required>                
                     <br><label><b>email</b></label><br>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" required><br>
                               <br><label><b>USERNAME</b></label><br>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter username" name="uname" required><br>
                            <br><label><b>password</b></label><br>
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="pass" required><br>
                            <br><label><b>Re-password</b></label><br>
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="rpass" required><br>
                    <button type="SUBMIT">SUBMIT</button>
                    </div>
              </form>

  </div>

</div>
```

---

```
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal1-content">
    <span class="close1">&times;</span>
       <form action="asignup.php">
              <div class="container">
                 <label><b>NAME<b></label><br>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Fullname" name="fname" required>                
                     <br><label><b>email</b></label><br>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter email" name="email" required><br>
                               <br><label><b>USERNAME</b></label><br>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter username" name="uname" required><br>
                            <br><label><b>password</b></label><br>
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="pass" required><br>
                            <br><label><b>Re-password</b></label><br>
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="rpass" required><br>
                    <button type="SUBMIT">SUBMIT</button>
                    </div>
              </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

We have mainly 2 PHPs for the signup option. "asignup.php" and "csignup.php".

But on clicking submit, on either of the forms, redirects and uses the "asignup.php".

We are not able to redirect to "csignup.php", even though we have specified it as the form action for one of the forms. Please take a look through it, and help us out.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see a problem with the code above but could please show the code for the whole page, as there could be other things causing this issue.

Comment: Since the 2 forms are completely identical except for the form action, I'd recommend you to check if the right modal opens by inspecting the html and see if the form has the right action you want it to have.